# Renting vs. owning comparison calculation

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, finance

I have working code that compares rental prices and owning costs, given some parameters. It works, but it surely does not look good. I hadn't worked with time-series before and I wonder how I could improve the code. See it below:

```
""" Credit: khanacademy.org/downloads/buyrent.xls"""

""" This code compares the cost of renting with the cost of owning a house.
It was orginally thought for the US case. The adjustment of parameteres was made
to fit the case of Brazil. Two alternatives are available the so-called Price table or SAC:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_Amortização_Constante"""


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def flow(purchase_p, downpay, inter, yr, prop_tax_rate, yr_maint, yr_cond, yr_ins, appr, inc_tax_rate, inflat,
     rent_price, cash, print_ten=120, choice='price'):

    if choice == 'price':
        fixed_mortgage_payment = (purchase_p - downpay) * (1 - 1/(1 + inter/12)) / (1 - 1/(1 + inter/12) **
                                                                                (yr * 12 + 1))
    else:
        fixed_mortgage_payment = (purchase_p - downpay) / (yr * 12)

    home_value = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    debt = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    paid_interest = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    insurance = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    cond = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    maint = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    property_tax = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    cash_outflow = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    rent = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    rent_savings = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    paid_principal = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)
    income_tax = np.zeros(yr * 12 + 1)

    home_value[0] = purchase_p
    debt[0] = purchase_p - downpay
    insurance[0] = yr_ins/12
    cond[0] = yr_cond/12
    maint[0] = yr_maint/12
    rent[0] = rent_price
    rent_savings[0] = downpay

    for i in range(yr * 12):
        paid_interest[i + 1] = debt[i] * inter / 12
        if choice == 'price':
            paid_principal[i + 1] = fixed_mortgage_payment - paid_interest[i + 1]
            debt[i + 1] = debt[i] - paid_principal[i + 1]
        else:
            paid_principal[i + 1] = fixed_mortgage_payment
            debt[i + 1] = debt[i] - fixed_mortgage_payment

        home_value[i + 1] = home_value[i] * (1 + appr/12)
        insurance[i + 1] = insurance[i] * (1 + inflat/12)
        cond[i + 1] = cond[i] * (1 + inflat/12)
        maint[i + 1] = maint[i] * (1 + inflat / 12)
        property_tax[i + 1] = home_value[i] * (prop_tax_rate/12)
        income_tax[i + 1] = (paid_interest[i + 1] + property_tax[i + 1]) * inc_tax_rate
        cash_outflow[i + 1] = insurance[i + 1] + cond[i + 1] + maint[i + 1] + property_tax[i + 1] + \
                          paid_interest[i + 1] + paid_principal[i + 1] - income_tax[i + 1]
        rent[i + 1] = (1 + appr/12) * rent[i]
        rent_savings[i + 1] = rent_savings[i] * (1 + cash/12) + cash_outflow[i + 1] - rent[i + 1]

    print('Home value after {:.0f} years: {:,.2f}'.format(print_ten/12, home_value[print_ten]))
    print('Debt after {:.0f} years: {:,.2f}'.format(print_ten/12, debt[print_ten]))
    print('Equity after {:.0f} years: {:,.2f}'.format(print_ten/12, home_value[print_ten] - debt[print_ten]))
    print('Savings if renting after {:.0f} years: {:,.2f}'.format(print_ten/12, rent_savings[print_ten]))
    print('Selling cost (6% brokerage rate): {:,.2f}'.format(home_value[print_ten] * .06))
    print('Benefit of buying over renting? {:,.2f}'.format(home_value[print_ten] - debt[print_ten]
                                                       - rent_savings[print_ten] - home_value[print_ten] * .06))
    return {'home_value': home_value, 'debt': debt, 'equity': home_value - debt, 'savings_renting': rent_savings,
        'benefit_buying': home_value - debt - rent_savings - (home_value * .06)}


def plotting(data):
    plt.plot(data['home_value'], label='Home value')
    plt.plot(data['debt'], label='Debt')
    plt.plot(data['equity'], label='Equity')
    plt.plot(data['savings_renting'], label="Savings when renting")
    plt.plot(data['benefit_buying'], label='Benefit of buying')
    plt.legend()
    plt.annotate('Parms: house price {:,.0f}, \ndownpayment {:,.0f}, \ninterest annual {:.3f}, years {:.0f}, '
                 '\naluguel {:,.0f}, \ncash return annual {:.3f}, \ninflation {:.3f},'
                 '\ntabela: {} \nhouse appreciation {:.3f}'.format(purchase_price, downpayment, interest, years,
                                                                   initial_rent, return_cash, inflation, choice,
                                                                   appreciation),
                 fontsize=9, xy=(0.43, 0.7), xycoords='axes fraction')
    plt.savefig('res1.png')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    purchase_price = 800000
    downpayment = 0
    interest = .08
    years = 30
    property_tax_rate = 0
    yr_maintenance = 0
    yr_comdominium = 0
    yr_insurance = 0
    appreciation = .03  # real appreciation 0%
    income_tax_rate = 0 # income deduction on interest and property taxes paid
    inflation = .03
    initial_rent = purchase_price * .004 # 0.4 % of real values
    return_cash = .06   # real return on cash 3%

    time = 360
    choice = 'SAC'

    res = flow(purchase_price, downpayment, interest, years, property_tax_rate, yr_maintenance, yr_comdominium,
    yr_insurance, appreciation, income_tax_rate, inflation, initial_rent, return_cash, time, choice)
    plotting(res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't cover everything that can be done to improve the code, so I will start by the most important parts. Once you incorporate these, you can post the updated version as a new question

## variable names

the naming of functions, variables etc is more than half of the documentation of your code, so you should be very careful with it. Saving a few characters like `maint` instead of `yearly_maintenance`is not worth it. It made me go back and forth between the method definition and place where you call the method a few times.

Also make it clear which cost is yearly, and which is monthly.

You can also include some intermediary variable to clarify some things: `loaned_amount = purchase_price - downpayment`

## split calculation with presentation

Your code both calculates the costs and gain, and does a lot of the presentation (for example `print('Home value after {:.0f} years: {:,.2f}'.format(print_ten/12, home_value[print_ten]))`) in the same method. Separating these two will make testing the code and algorithm a lot easier. If you want to build a GUI later, you will be able to reuse the calculation, which is rather difficult now due to all the side-effects (`print`)

## vectorize

The costs which don't change every year, apart from appreciation or inflation, which are all apart from the loan repayments, can be easily vectorized:

```
months = years * 12
months_array = np.arange(months + 1)
home_value = purchase_price * (1 + appreciation / 12) ** months_array
maintenance = yearly_maintenance / 12 * (1 + inflation / 12) ** months_array
```

and then later summed.

## split of more parts

The calculation of the amount due each month, or the amortization can be easily split of in different function

```
def monthly_payment(*, loaned_amount, months, monthly_interest_rate):
    return (
        loaned_amount
        * (1 - 1 / (1 + monthly_interest_rate))
        / (1 - 1 / (1 + monthly_interest_rate) ** (months))
    )
```

little exta comments is needed. The method does what it said in the name and variables. The only thing which might need explanation is the algorithm used.

```
def amortize(*, loaned_amount, yearly_interest_rate, monthly_payment):
    monthly_interest_rate = yearly_interest_rate / 12
    principal_paid = 0
    interest = 0
    yield loaned_amount, interest, principal_paid
    while loaned_amount * (1+monthly_interest_rate) >= monthly_payment:
        interest = loaned_amount * monthly_interest_rate
        principal_paid = monthly_payment - interest
        loaned_amount = loaned_amount - principal_paid
        yield loaned_amount, interest, principal_paid

    interest = loaned_amount * monthly_interest_rate  
    yield 0, interest, loaned_amount
```

Here, a `generator` is more clear than appending items to 3 different lists, and then returning the lists in the end.

For both I used keyword-only arguments, which are a lot clearer after 2 years (no more questions: `what argument came first...`)

and they are called like this:

```
elif system.lower() == "price":
    monthly_amount = monthly_payment(
        loaned_amount=loaned_amount,
        months=months,
        monthly_interest_rate=yearly_interest_rate / 12,
    )
    amortization = np.array(
        list(
            amortize(
                loaned_amount=loaned_amount,
                yearly_interest_rate=yearly_interest_rate,
                monthly_payment=monthly_amount,
            )
        )
    )
    debt, interest_paid, principal_paid = np.split(amortization, 3, axis=1)
```

## line length

Some of your lines were very long, requiring horizontal scrolling. Try to limit the length of the lines of code. I use the [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) formatter to take care of line lengths etc for me.

## the whole thing

A (simplified) version of the `flow` method:

```
def flow(
    purchase_price,
    downpayment,
    yearly_interest_rate,
    years,
    property_tax_rate,
    yearly_maintenance,
    yearly_comdominium,
    yearly_insurance,
    appreciation,
    income_tax_rate,
    inflation,
    initial_rent,
    return_cash,
    time,
    system,
):
    months = years * 12
    months_array = np.arange(months + 1)
    home_value = purchase_price * (1 + appreciation / 12) ** months_array
    maintenance = yearly_maintenance / 12 * (1 + inflation / 12) ** months_array
    insurance = yearly_insurance / 12 * (1 + inflation / 12) ** months_array

    loaned_amount = purchase_price - downpayment

    if system.upper() == "SAC":
        debt = loaned_amount * (1 - months_array / months)
        interest_paid = loaned_amount * yearly_interest_rate / 12
        principal_paid = loaned_amount / months * np.ones_like(months_array)

    elif system.lower() == "price":
        monthly_amount = monthly_payment(
            loaned_amount=loaned_amount,
            months=months,
            monthly_interest_rate=yearly_interest_rate / 12,
        )
        amortization = np.array(
            list(
                amortize(
                    loaned_amount=loaned_amount,
                    yearly_interest_rate=yearly_interest_rate,
                    monthly_payment=monthly_amount,
                )
            )
        )
        debt, interest_paid, principal_paid = np.split(amortization, 3, axis=1)

    property_tax = home_value * property_tax_rate
    income_tax = (interest_paid + property_tax) * income_tax_rate
    cash_outflow = (
        insurance
        + maintenance
        + property_tax
        + interest_paid
        + principal_paid
        - income_tax
    )
    rent = initial_rent * (1 + appreciation / 12) ** months_array

    rent_savings = (cash_outflow - rent) * (
        1 + return_cash / 12
    ) ** months_array

    return months, debt, rent_savings
```

the `return` statement can be expanded. Instead of all the arrays in a `tuple`, I would combine the either in a `dict` or a `pandas.DataFrame`.

This can be called like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    purchase_price = 800000
    downpayment = 0
    interest = 0.08
    years = 20
    property_tax_rate = 0
    yearly_maintenance = 100
    yearly_comdominium = 0
    yearly_insurance = 0
    appreciation = 0.03  # real appreciation 0%
    income_tax_rate = 0  # income deduction on interest and property taxes paid
    inflation = 0.03
    initial_rent = purchase_price * 0.004  # 0.4 % of real values
    return_cash = 0.06  # real return on cash 3%

    time = 240
    choice = "sac"
    months, debt, rent_savings = flow(
        purchase_price,
        downpayment,
        interest,
        years,
        property_tax_rate,
        yearly_maintenance,
        yearly_comdominium,
        yearly_insurance,
        appreciation,
        income_tax_rate,
        inflation,
        initial_rent,
        return_cash,
        time,
        choice,
    )
    rent_savings.sum()
```